# Limiting the transfer rate of imageIO.write over socket

Tags: java, sockets, javax.imageio

I've done some research on this, and I have seen some responses for limiting data transfer using a sleep. However my method of sending the image is via a buffered image over imageIO rather than a byte array etc.

```
DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

ImageIO.write(captureImg(),"JPG",client.getOutputStream());
```

Basically the program sends the captureImg over socket to a VPS. However I want to limit this transfer rate to something around 15kb/s. Is that possible with this method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a wrapper for the `OutputStream` -> the `write(...)` methods.

Take a look at [Guava's rate limiter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html), might come handy for solving that problem.

Comment: Thanks, ortang. Great link, I couldn't edit my previous comment if you saw it. I missed that second example that talks about limiting a stream of data.